# Glucose Oxidase, Condition to be Active?

Tags: bacteriology, enzyme-kinetics

I most recently was reading/watching information on honeys antibatical and antimicrobial properties.  The enzyme Glucose Oxidase came up often as a main antimicrobial, yet it is inactive in honey.  How much would honey need to be diluted to make this enyzme active? I may potentially use honey in a dilute for as a backpacking emergency antibiotic/antimicrobial and/or something to irrigate wounds if severe.

I do have an basic (High School) understanding of chemistry if that helps

Comment: An interesting point about honey for sure. But why would you prioritise honey over medical supplies whilst back-packing?

Comment: This is a common "alternative medicine" claim. But: Where do you see honey being used as an effective medicine? Don't rely on something which will most likely not work (how would you get effective concentrations throughout your body for example) and use real medicine.